# Algorithm to partition a set into subsets of equal weight

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a big set of Marbles $M$ of various colors $m_c$, each $m_c$ is characterized by an integer weight $w_c$ and number of marbles of that color $n_c$. I would like an algorithm to split set $M$ into $N$ subsets $M_j$ such that the sum of weights in each subset is approximately equal.

For eg. If I have 3 colors of marbles Red, Green, Blue; each have weights $$w_r =1$$ $$w_g =2$$ $$w_b =3$$. And I have 5 Red marbles, 6 Green and 3 Blue, i.e. $$n_r =5$$ $$n_g =5$$ $$n_b =3$$
If I have to make them into 4 equal weighted subsets, $N = 4$. Then, i would make $$M_1 = {m_r * 1, m_g * 1, m_b * 1}$$ $$M_2 = {m_r * 1, m_g * 1, m_b * 1}$$ $$M_3 = {m_r * 1, m_g * 1, m_b * 1}$$ $$M_4 = {m_r * 2, m_g * 2}$$ so that $M_1 to M_4 have equal weights!

Coming from a computer science background, I wonder whether a Mathematical algorithm for this problem exists.

Comment: You might try asking this on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But as far as I can tell, your problem is exactly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning.

Comment: (And it's NP-hard)

Comment: @Milten THank you! It seems that the Identical-machines scheduling a type of Multiway_number_partitioning, suits my problem statement the best. I am trying out few algorithms available. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem, hope it helps :)